# Error launching Android Studio after latest update

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Error launching Android Studio**

I updated **Android Studio** to version **1.3.2** now unable to start **Android Studio.**

[image]

I have set `JAVA_HOME` and `path` variable correctly still same error.

[image]

**EDIT**

```
 C:\Users\Webspidy 2>java -version 

 java version "1.7.0_71" Java(TM) SE
 Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
 (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: What says cmd: java -version ?

Comment: I faced similar issue on windows 8. After running as Administrator Android studio came up.

Comment: @user8218 check edit

Comment: Delete java files from my answer from C:\Windows\System32\. It helps. If you don't want delete them just cut to another directory

Comment: And for changing PATH values I've found great free app http://www.rapidee.com/en/about

Comment: @user8218 it doesn't make me sense.